# R Markdown - Open .Rmd with shyni runtime outside R

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a document with Rmarkdown on RStudio. In that rmd I use shiny runtime and my question is if I could generate some file with that document to open it outside RStudio, just like rmd without shiny runtime which generates an .html.

I was searching but I found nothing, does anyone know some tool to do that?

Many thanks!

Xevi

Comment: Rmarkdown doesn't depend on RStudio at all -- the rendering functions only require R.  Without a runtime dependency on shiny, you could use `render` to output a self-contained .html file without any R dependency as well

Comment: IIRC I used to use something like `Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::run("my.Rmd", shiny_args=list(launch.browser=TRUE), ...)'`